# Error in dbPreExists && !overwrite : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

Tags: r, postgresql, sqldf, rpostgresql

I'm executing SQL using RPostgreSQL and sqldf packages.

Connection:

```
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="dbname",host="host",port=5432,user="usr",password="pwd")
```

Then I build a pretty complex SQL statement and at the end I have (`vSQL` is the SQL select statement):

```
vSQLDF <- sqldf(vSQL, connection=con)
```

Now I get the following error:

```
Error in dbPreExists && !overwrite : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

I was not able to create any reproducible example, all I can say is:

1. The generated SQL statement works when executed directly in the database (I've copied the string from R to pgAdmin)
2. The connection works, I can use `sqldf("select * from any_table, connection=con")`
3. It works when I generate shorter SQL using different input parameters for my script
4. The SQL length only is not a problem, I've tried: `inSQL =  paste(rep("select 1::int ",10000),collapse=" union all ")`, which results in different error: `RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded`
5. There are no strange characters in my SQL statement

Any idea what this error means?

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=cs_CZ.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=cs_CZ.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] tcltk     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lattice_0.20-13       sqldf_0.4-6.4         RSQLite.extfuns_0.0.1 RSQLite_0.11.2        chron_2.3-43          gsubfn_0.6-5         
 [7] proto_0.3-10          RPostgreSQL_0.3-3     DBI_0.2-5            

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.2  tools_2.15.2
```

PostgreSQL:

```
PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit
```

RStudio 0.97.332

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Response](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqldf/FrpCzdJ-tM4) from Gabor Grothendieck:

> I don't think manual connections were ever tested with postgres.  Use
>   RPostgreSQL directly if you want to use those.
>
> Manual and automatic connections do work in sqldf with sqlite and
>   automatic connections do work in sqldf with RPostgreSQL.

See his original post for entire response.

Answer (score 1):

Without the code and a modest amount of background detail, this is just a guessing game, but I see nowhere that you have configured sqldf to use a different driver than the default with the appropriate options. You have not mentioned that you have followed all the instructions relevant to PostgreSQL  in the [sqldf page at googlecode.com:](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#12._How_does_one_use_sqldf_with_PostgreSQL?)

In the sqldf code is a line:

```
if (request.con) dbPreExists <- attr(connection, "dbPreExists")
```

You can perhaps get insight by supplyin g you connection object to a similar call:

```
dbPreExists <- attr(connection, "dbPreExists") #see error gets thrown.
```

You can also debug sqldf with:

```
debug(sqldf)  # then repeat operation
```

A browser session will be started and you can single step through the process.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought someone has seen this type of error before. The problem is that I have two valid SQL queries and one them just returns this cryptic error using sqldf. It won't help if I copy the code here as both SQLs are really long and with complex business logic. Btw. my connection is defined correctly, see the first two lines of code where `con` is defined, including PostgreSQL driver.

Comment: I saw the first two lines. I didn't see mention that the options had been set as specified in the cited page.